# Canon TS705 printer - Paper Source option Not Available

Tags: printing, canon

I recently purchased a  Pixma TS 705 printer & am using it via USB in Ubuntu 19.04 with Canon driver from cnijfilter2-5.80-1-deb.tar.gz.

Generally it is working well.

But I am only able to load paper from the front cassette & not from the rear tray.
In the print control window, under the tab "Page Setup", the item "Paper source" says "Not available" & is greyed out & cannot be used.

It works OK in W10...

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I cheated printer. Set different papers for trays, set appropriate paper type for tray you want and printer will use proper tray.